# Problema con argumento extra al usar decoradores en Python

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.7, sqlite3, decoradores

Estoy haciendo un programa muy básico para manejar una BD en Python con SQLite3. Al momento de conectarme, hacer `commit` y desconectarme de la BD tengo que hacer esto.

```py
conexion = sqlite3.connect("Mi_BD.db")
cursor = conexion.cursor()

# acá va el código donde uso la variable cursor para escribir el SQL

conexion.commit()
conexion.close()
```

Pero esto lo tengo que hacer repetidas veces, así que decidí usar un decorador

```py
def connect_disconnect_BD(fun):
    def funcion_b(x,*args):
        conexion = sqlite3.connect("Mi_BD.db")
        cursor = conexion.cursor()

        fun(cursor,*args)

        conexion.commit()
        conexion.close()
    return funcion_b
```

De esta forma puedo conectarme, hacer commit y desconectarme de la BD llamando al decorador:

```py
@connect_disconnect_BD
def crear_persona(cursor,nombre,apellido,pais):
    cursor.execute(f"""
        INSERT INTO PERSONA VALUES ('{nombre}', '{apellido}', '{pais}')
    """)

crear_persona("","Pedro","Lopez","Argentina")
```

Tengo un inconveniente al momento de llamar a la función `crear_persona()` porque si se dan cuenta tengo que pasar un argumento al inicio que está vacío (`""`), ya que este supuestamente recibe el `cursor`, pero el `cursor` lo pasa en la función decoradora `connect_disconnect_BD`.

Mi pregunta es **¿QUÉ TENGO QUE HACER PARA QUE LA FUNCION CREAR PERSONA NO RECIBA UN ARGUMENTO `""`?**

Comment: Quítale el argumento obligatorio x a funcion_b

Comment: Wow, sólo era eso, había probado muchas formas y no consideré quitarle ese x. muchas gracias

Comment: De nada Ismael!